# Regex to find text between expressions, where the end of one match might be the start of the next

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, match

I'd like to match the text between each line starting "2 capacitors", "1 op-amp", etc. in the following data using Python 3.5:

```
#Sat Dec 16 09:10:37 2017
#
#2 capacitors:
#  0 c1 10 uF GND n1 
#  1 c2 47 pF nm nout 
#1 op-amp:
#  0 o1 lt1124 '+'=nin '-'=nm 'out'=nout a0=15M gbw=14.6 MHz 
#       un=2.7 nV/sqrt(Hz) uc=2.3 Hz in=300 fA/sqrt(Hz) ic=100 Hz 
#       umax=12 V imax=20 mA sr=4.5 V/us delay=18.9 ns 
#       pole at 200 kHz (real)        pole at 200 kHz (real)        zero at 800 kHz (real)        zero at 800 kHz (real)        zero at 9.4 MHz (real) 
#2 resistors:
#  0 r1 430 Ohm n1 nm
#  1 r2 43 kOhm nm nout
#4 nodes:
#  0 n1
#  1 nm
#  2 nout
#  3 nin
#Logarithmic frequency scale from 1 Hz to 100 kHz in 100 steps.
```

I'd like to extract:

**match 1**: `(2, capacitors, #  0 c1 10 uF GND n1#  1 c2 47 pF nm nout)`

**match 2**: `(1, op-amp, #  0 o1 lt1124 '+'=nin '-'=nm 'out'=nout a0=15M gbw=14.6 MHz#  un=2.7 nV/sqrt(Hz) uc=2.3 Hz in=300 fA/sqrt(Hz) ic=100 Hz.......)`

**match 3**: `(2, resistors, #  0 r1 430 Ohm n1 nm#  1 r2 43 kOhm nm nout)`

**match 4**: `(4, nodes, #  0 n1#  1 nm#  2 nout#  3 nin)`

Whether or not the third group retains newlines is not important to me. Currently, I match by searching for the text between the first match and the first line that is not whitespace:

```
^\#(\d+) (op\-amps|op\-amp|capacitors|capacitor|resistors|resistor|nodes|node):$([\d\D]*?)^#\S
```

[regexr example](https://regexr.com/3i4fh)

(The `MULTILINE` flag must be enabled. The `[\d\D]` trick is to match all characters including newlines on different platforms.)

The problem is that the `1 op-amp` and `4 nodes` segments don't match because they form part of the previous match: for example, the `#1 op-amp` line. How can I get all of the possible matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optimized solution:

```
import re

with open('yourfile.txt') as f:
    pat = r'^#(\d+) (op-amps?|capacitors?|resistors?|nodes?):([\s\S]+?)(?=\n#\S+ )'
    result = re.findall(pat, f.read(), re.M)
    for m in result:
        print(m)
```

The output:

```
('2', 'capacitors', '\n#  0 c1 10 uF GND n1 \n#  1 c2 47 pF nm nout ')
('1', 'op-amp', "\n#  0 o1 lt1124 '+'=nin '-'=nm 'out'=nout a0=15M gbw=14.6 MHz \n#       un=2.7 nV/sqrt(Hz) uc=2.3 Hz in=300 fA/sqrt(Hz) ic=100 Hz \n#       umax=12 V imax=20 mA sr=4.5 V/us delay=18.9 ns \n#       pole at 200 kHz (real)        pole at 200 kHz (real)        zero at 800 kHz (real)        zero at 800 kHz (real)        zero at 9.4 MHz (real) ")
('2', 'resistors', '\n#  0 r1 430 Ohm n1 nm\n#  1 r2 43 kOhm nm nout')
('4', 'nodes', '\n#  0 n1\n#  1 nm\n#  2 nout\n#  3 nin')
```

---

Details:

- `<word>s?`- matches zero or one `s` ending char of `<word>`
- `[\s\S]+?` - matches any character sequence `[\s\S]` between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
- `(?=\n#\S+ )` - lookahead positive assertion, ensures that the needed sequence of matches is followed by `\n#\S+` (separate line starting with `#` and non-whitespace char sequence `\S+`)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot for the solution and explanation.